# Кнопки уезжают за границу формы

Tags: css, less

Css формы:

```
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font-family: $font_elp;
background-color: #f4f6f9;
max-width: 100%;
color: $main-font-color;
padding: 10px;
```

Css кнопки:

```
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font-family: $font_elp;
background-color: #f4f6f9;
max-width: 100%;
color: $main-font-color;
padding: 10px;
```

Также у всех элементов:

```
.call-form {
    * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://jsfiddle.net/lebedevvladimir/pcm98Lw6/

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433430/border-botton-у-div-сверху

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугли `clearfix`.

Ну или так:

```
.wrapper-content .call-form {
    /* ... */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcm98Lw6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Выглядит так, как-будто здесь не все стили.
Попробуйте оформить всё на JSFiddle.

Похожая проблема может возникнуть в случае не обнуленных float у кнопок или фиксированной ширины у родительского блока, а так же, если есть отрицательные отступы.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lebedevvladimir/pcm98Lw6/
Оформил здесь.

Answer (score -1):

Пропишите

```
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Потом добавьте класс clearfix к блоку в html.